# Custom Keyboard in webview android

Tags: android, webview, cordova, android-softkeyboard, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have created custom keyboard and extends InputMethodService implements OnKeyboardActionListener.

when user tap on any key then i explicitly call KeyEvent like.

```
event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

Now, It is working fine in google.com search text box. But when i change the setting

[Google Setting](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186610?hl=en) and choose Never shows instant result and Save

Then my keyboard will not work. This issue is only faces in Nexus 7 android version 4.2

I am very glad if anyone can help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue is not relavent to KeyEvent.
It may possible your textBox is not getting focus,
for example you are setting focus some where else like :
**your_webView.requestFocusFromTouch(); or focusing the dialog**

So the solution is just remove the focus if you are setting, else part will be maintain by system itself.